# How do you handle multiple validation errors with GraphQL and Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, graphql, apollo-server

folks. I'm working with a user registration resolver using Apollo Server, and I'm not sure how we're supposed to go about handling multiple errors being thrown from model validation stuff from Mongoose.

As of right now, I have this current model that I am using to store users for this tiny app that I'm working on:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: (value) => validator.isEmail(value),
            message: (data) => `${data.value} is not a valid e-mail address!`
        },
        unique: true
    },
    digest: String,
});
```

I'm using `mongoose-unique-validator` to ensure that `username` and `email` are unique, and if not, errors are thrown.

The problem is, I don't know how to handle both of these errors being thrown at the same time (if both `email` and `username` are invalid when a document is `.save()`d).

I tested this case using GraphQL Playground, and this is what I get when these validations are both triggered (and both fail):

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Couldn't create user: ValidationError: email: Error, expected `email` to be unique. Value: `test@test2.com`, username: Error, expected `username` to be unique. Value: `test4`",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createUser"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "Error: Couldn't create user: ValidationError: email: Error, expected `email` to be unique. Value: `test@test2.com`, username: Error, expected `username` to be unique. Value: `test4`",
            "    at /Users/trashpanda/Projects/roma/server/src/graphql/resolvers.js:19:27",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "createUser": null
  }
}
```

From what I understand from the docs, optimally I want to receive an array of errors that I can iterate through, but I'm not sure how to achieve this, as Mongoose is just concatenating both of the validation errors into one message that's being thrown as one singular error.

Here's the resolver:

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { ApolloError } from 'apollo-server-express';
import validator from 'validator';
import { User } from '../db/db';

const resolvers = {
    Mutation: {
        createUser: (_, args) => {
            const {username, password, email} = args;
            return bcrypt.hash(password, 12)
                .then((digest) => {
                     const doc = { username, digest, email };
                     const newUser = new User(doc);
                     return newUser.save();
                })
                .then((doc) => {
                    return doc;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    throw new ApolloError(`Couldn't create user: ${err}`);
                });
        }
    }
};

export default resolvers;
```

Is there something I need to do with Apollo Server in terms of how I'm using `.catch()` in the Promise for `.save()`? I'm confused. I just know that I'm going to want to be able to check for both errors independently on the client (for stuff like highlighting input fields, etc), so I figure I need to have it throw an array of errors, not just one "bundled" one.

Thoughts?